# Laravel 4 not able to catch Exception

Tags: exception, laravel

I have tried to isolate this problem (to produce it outside my app), but I can't.

```
try {
    $has_cache = Cache::has($cache_key);
}
catch (DecryptException $e) {
    echo "No biggie";
    exit;
}
```

I also tried with a `catch (Exception $e)`, the same thing happens.

Using this code, I get a DecryptException in the second line. How can this happen, it's in the try block?

Like I said, I tried to do the same on a clean project, but there it caught the exception, so I'm asking where could I have messed something up.

Comment: There may be more than one DecryptException classes, it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: I've updated my question, as I have tried to use "catch (Exception $e)" and this also didn't work.

Comment: could you add the actual error message?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If your application is *namespaced*, you would need to use

```php
catch(\Exception $e);
// or preferably
catch(\RuntimeException $e);
```

likewise, I think the `DecryptException` you are trying to catch is namespaced in `Illuminate\Encryption` so you'd need

```php
catch(\Illuminate\Encryption\DecryptException)
// or use "use" somewhere before the try/catch
use \Illuminate\Encryption\DecryptException
```

**Keep in mind** that Laravel 4 is still **alpha** or **pre-beta** (apparently they are not sure themselves), so it is in no way stable and probably not the best choice for production.

Comment: +1 for your answer. Working in a namespace is really messing me up.  Is there any way to just declare "uses /" or something?  It's kind of irritating to have to backslash every global class..

Comment: With the bracket-syntax you can define `namespace { /* code here */}` (without an identifier after the `namespace` keyword) then global classes don't need an `\ `, but you can't define a namespaced class in it (`class a\b {}` is not valid) and you can't nest them, so it probably won't do you much good. For functions and constants at least a fallback is built in that loads them from the global NS if not found in the current NS. Of course you can always `use Foo, Bar, Baf;` (where `Foo`, etc. are classes in the global space)

Comment: Actually, you should open a question, maybe someone else knows a better option, as I'm not a big fan of how PHP implemented namespaces (very mildly put) and try to avoid them and PHP in general now

Comment: I had an api, whose routes were grouped with a namespace. The corresponding classes were respectively namespaced as well, so it took me quite some time to realize that I need to use the global namespace for the exceptions - `\Exception` if I want them to be caught in the api.

Answer (score 4):

For laravel 5.1 you should write(generally at start of the file with other use statements):

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;
```

Before catch statement:

```
try {
    $data = \Crypt::decrypt($key);
} catch (DecryptException $e) {
    echo 'caught exception';
    exit();
}
```

Ref:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/encryption - under "Decrypting A Value"

May be helpful for others.